# ASP Label Replace new line

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, newline

Hello I have an label in my project that gets its text from a database but because the label does not support the multline method i need to convert new lines to 
 i tried using `TweetLabel.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")`
but it does not work.
I'l add images showing the problem. [image: Source code from browser]

[image: Render of it]

[image: Database record]

Comment: Have you made sure that you are actually using the br tag in your served HTML in your browser?

Comment: yes the tag has an edit before this edit and the first edit works

Comment: explain it more please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.Replace() returns a new string. It doesn't change the string you put into the method. Therefore `TweetLabel.Text.Replace()` on its own will do nothing. You need to change it to:

```
TweetLabel.Text = TweetLabel.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```